# Surface Pro 4 screenshot filename different than it used to be. How do I change it back?

Tags: windows-10, filenames, screenshot, print-screen, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have the screenshots on my surface that are in my OneDrive Pictures folder. They are formatted like `2017-06-27.png`.

The first one is `2016-01-10` but the last one I have is from August (`2017-08-07`). Now whenever I take a screenshot it's named `Screenshot (#).png` with incremental numbers. I hate that format.

I prefer the old way with the date stamp as the filename. I have no idea why it changed. I know I didn't change a setting for this and don't think there is one anyway.

Anyone have some ideas why this changed in August (maybe some update) and how I can get it to go back?

As an aside, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> also no longer works for taking screenshots, which is what I always used before. Now I have to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. I assume these two issues might be part of the same issue, but have no idea how to get it to format the filenames the way it used to with the timestamp, which I prefer.

This is all on Windows 10.

Comment: It sounds like a friendly windows update messed things up. Not that I know much about Wind 10 updates... I just came to suggest that using the Snipping Tool (start menu, then "sn" brings it up) usually works better than print screen these days, though you'd need to type the name yourself when you save it. Maybe you already know about it, great, but it seems a lot of people never use it so I thought I'd mention it in case it is a useful workflow.